# 'Details' button missing on installed app - in regards to performing an upgrade action

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

I am trying to perform an upgrade action on my SPFx web-part. In order to do so it is my understanding that I need to access this menu item called 'Details', but that seems to be missing on this app that I have developed, however it is present on this third party 'React Content Query' app (see image). How do I make this 'Details' menu item appear?

[image: Details missing]

Answer (score 0):

You can try switching to the classic experience to see if it is displayed.

If it still doesn't, you can try to re-deploy it.

You can refer to the article below:

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/blob/master/docs/sp-add-ins/create-custom-actions-to-deploy-with-sharepoint-add-ins.md